# Command or Powershell to Run All Tests in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I can run my unit test dll using the command below:

```
dotnet test "xxxx.UnitTests.dll"
```

But this displays the results in the console. Is there a command that opens and run all tests in the Test Explorer window?

Comment: "Is there a command that opens and run all tests in the Test Explorer window?" Is a bit unclear... do you wan to run all test from a given directory? What have you tried? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test

Comment: @Jocke Thank you. The link you provided is indeed helpful but it displays the output in a console. I want to run all tests in the solution automatically and display the result in the Test Explorer GUI.

Comment: I see, and you to to trigger the test run from the command line?

Comment: @Jocke Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first we would want to publish the results in a .trx file.

```
dotnet test C:\Source\MyProject\MyProject.Tests.csproj --logger trx --results-directory C:\Source\MyProject\TestResults\
```

or as your already running from you project folder we dont even need to specify the test .csproj file.

```
dotnet test --logger trx --results-directory TestResults\
```

After that we can double click the .trx file in the new TestResults folder or launch the file programmatically this will open up a vs test explorer window